# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}\sum\limits_{k\le n}\left\lfloor{k^3 x}\right \rfloor$

Tags: limits

I would like to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n^4}\left(\left \lfloor{1^3 x}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{2^3 x}\right \rfloor + \cdots+ \left \lfloor{n^3 x}\right \rfloor\right)$$

I thought of taking $n^4$ common in the first step but I am confused about how to take a factor common from within the floor function.

I also tried writing $\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor  = x + \{x\}$

Any help will be appreciated ...Thanks.
I'm willing to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Why 3 times *Any help will be appreciated ...Thanks if need more details will help*???

Comment: You should try to use MathJax to type mathematical formulae in your posts. It makes it easier to read. This link should help, do check it out: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net by mistake

Answer (score 1):

A common idea for limits involving the floor function is the [squeeze theroem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Let the required limit be $L$.
Note that
$$ r^3x\le\left \lfloor{r^3 x}\right \rfloor \le r^3x+1 ~~~; r \in \{1,2, \cdots,n\}  $$
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r^3x \le \sum_{r=1}^n\left \lfloor{r^3 x}\right \rfloor \le \sum_{r=1}^n(r^3x+1)$$
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{r=1}^n r^3x}{n^4} \le L \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{r=1}^n(r^3x+1)}{n^4}$$
Now use the identity
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3 = \dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} $$
What's left is a $\dfrac{\text{Polynomial}}{\text{Polynomial}}  $ limit which is fairly easy to evaluate.